# Sum on digits of powers of two is not too large

Tags: elementary-number-theory, open-problem

Is the following proved:

Are there infinitely many positive integers $m$ and an integer $n$ such that sum of digits of $2^m$ is at most $n$?

Comment: For a particular max m there is definitely a limit n.

Comment: The sum of the digits of $2^m$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A001370 where it says "It is believed that $a(n) \asymp 9n\log_10(2)/2$, but this is an open problem." It is believed even more strongly that the sum of the digits goes to infinity, but I think that one is open, too.

Comment: That comment got typoed --- $a(n)$ is believed to be asymptotic to $9/2$ times $n$ times log-base-10 of 2 (as in Julian's answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to be a comment.

Let $\phi(m)=\text{sum of digits of }m$. You ask if $\liminf_{m\to\infty}\phi(m)<\infty$. $2^m$ has $m\,\log_{10}2$ digits. The mean of the $9$ digits is $4.5$. We expect
$$
\phi(m)\sim4.5\,\log_{10}2\,n=1.35463498\,m.
$$

I have computed $\phi(m)$ for $1\le m\le 100000$. The mean value of $\phi(m)/m$ is $1.3548$ with variance $0.000244$, in agreement with the above. Here is the histogram:

[image]